# Ransack for two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am getting my heads around many things RoR - by developing a small movie database that has actors and movies.

I successfully setup Ransack to do two things for me:

1. Following Chris' great tutorial on autocomplete https://gorails.com/episodes/global-autocomplete-search I now have a working search field in my navbar with dropdown, autoselect etc - all works like charm :)
2. Set up a separate "moviesearch" method in my mainpage controller - with corresponding form etc - working great too.
   Code of moviesearch method:

   @q = Movie.ransack(params[:q]
   @movies_search = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:genres, :actors)

However I now try to setup an "actorsearch" method - also in my mainpage controller - with corresponding form etc... doesn't work. It does reply the right index page (view/actors/index.html.erb), but it doesn't pass any of the search parameters on.
Code of actorsearch method:

```
@q = Actor.ransack(params[:q])
@actors_search = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:movies, :actor_attributes)
```

When I check the console - the moviesearch method triggers something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `movies`.* FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`title` LIKE '%lord%' ORDER BY `movies`.`sort_title` ASC) subquery_for_count
```

But the actorsearch triggers only:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `actors`
```

Not sure what's wrong...

Update: Here's the form code for the actor search - omitted all html-only stuff (div's etc)

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>    
<%= f.label :display_name_cont, 'Name contains', class: 'form-label mb-0' %>
<%= f.search_field :display_name_cont, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.label :gender_eq, 'Gender is', class: 'form-label mb-0' %><%= f.search_field :gender_eq, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.label :actor_attributes_id_in, 'Attributes', class: 'form-label mb-0' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:actor_attributes_id_in, ActorAttribute.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { class: 'form-select bootstrap', id: 'attribute-select', multiple: true } ) %>
<%= f.label :born_gteq, 'Born between', class: 'form-label mb-0' %><%= f.number_field :born_gteq, class: 'form-control' %></div>
<%= f.label :born_lteq, 'and', class: 'form-label mb-0' %>
<%= f.number_field :born_lteq, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.label :rating_gteq, 'Actor rated at least', class: 'form-label mb-0' %>
<%= f.number_field :rating_gteq, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.label :movies_id_eq, 'Movies starring in', class: 'form-label mb-0' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:movies_id_in, Movie.order(:sort_title), :id, :title, {}, { class: 'form-select bootstrap', id: 'movie-select', multiple: true } ) %>
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And I didn't quite know what you mean with "puts params[:q] into the controller. I have already tried to check the params with outputting debug(params[:q]) in various places - for example, in my actors index page, it shows like this:

```
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  display_name_cont: john
  gender_eq: ''
  actor_attributes_id_in:
  - ''
  born_gteq: ''
  born_lteq: ''
  rating_gteq: ''
  movies_id_in:
  - ''
permitted: false
```

...which looks pretty similar to the output for movies... at least I couldn't spot any immediate issue here?

Comment: Can u sure the autosearch form code? also if in your controller you do puts params[:q] what does it output?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - added the code above. Not sure what  you mean with the "puts..." statement.

Comment: is `actors` table has `display_name` column ?

Comment: you can try `Actor.ransack!` which will raise errors if a query contains an unknown predicate or attribute to know whether the input parameters is valid or not.

Comment: found the problem :) - your comment pointed me to it .... I had the Actor.ransack.... stuff in the controller action that defines the SEARCH, but not the controller action that shows the RESULT - so I never parsed the q-Parameter! Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!